# zsh is not setting environment variable

Tags: variables, export, oh-my-zsh

I use oh-my-zsh. In a script I use

```sh
export DISPLAY=":1"
```

On the top a have a shebang, which is linked to bash.
The file has been `chmod +x`-ed, and is called directly with `./script`.
After running the script, the environment variable `DISPLAY` is empty. Using `export` in `.zshrc` works though.

Is there any configs for zsh to change, so that exports are working, or am I doing something wrong?